# SmoothState onAfter callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, smoothstate.js

I have a site that has elements like a slider on most pages. I am trying to implement the SmoothState JS but I am running into the issue of the second page breaking. I know through the documentation I probably need to add the `onAfter` callback but I was wondering where and how this would be applied. Apparently it can be tricky if unfamiliar with Ajax.

[Here is the documentation on the issue.](https://github.com/miguel-perez/smoothState.js#faq)

And this is the code that I have that fires the script:

```
$(function(){
  'use strict';
  var $page = $('#uber'),
      options = {
        debug: true,
        prefetch: true,
        cacheLength: 2,
        onStart: {
          duration: 250, // Duration of our animation
          render: function ($container) {
            // Add your CSS animation reversing class
            $container.addClass('is-exiting');
            // Restart your animation
            smoothState.restartCSSAnimations();
          }
        },
        onReady: {
          duration: 0,
          render: function ($container, $newContent) {
            // Remove your CSS animation reversing class
            $container.removeClass('is-exiting');
            // Inject the new content
            $container.html($newContent);
          }
        }
      },
      smoothState = $page.smoothState(options).data('smoothState');
});
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I would add the `onAfter` callback?

Answer (score 5):

I've just started trying out smoothState, but here is what first worked for me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  prep(); 
});

$('#main').smoothState({
  onAfter: function() {
    prep();
  }
});


function prep(){

      $('#loadBtn').click(function () { 

          $( '#remote1' ).load( 'external.html #myExternalDiv', function( response, status, xhr ) {
            if ( status == 'error' ) {
              var msg = 'Sorry but there was an error: ';
              $( '#error' ).html( msg + xhr.status + ' ' + xhr.statusText );
            }
            $('#remote1').slideToggle();
          });

      }); 

} // prep
```

So I put stuff that would normally go into my $(document).ready section into a prep() function.  Then I call that for both doc init and onAfter.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have a js file that's as long as my arm, but it works.